# How does URL without protocol works and should it be used in Web?

Tags: http, web, https, hyperlink, protocols

Let's say that I have a website with SSL certificate and if I type

```html
<a href="https://mywebsite.com"/>
```

it will send me to that website, and if I type

```html
<a href="http://mywebsite.com"/>
```

It will also send me to website with redirection to `https` protocol

If I have a website without SSL and link to it with

```html
<a href="https://mywebsite.com"/>
```

I will get something like 'Your connection is not private', or website wont load at all. Here is the catch.

If I link to website with

```html
<a href="//mywebsite.com"/>
```

It will send me to website if does or doesn't have SSL.

When clicking on link that is in this format, network tab reports status code 200 for that website, which means it is not redirection and it automatically goes to `http` or `https`.

My question here is how? It would be clear to me if it first tried `http` and then redirected to `https`, if it existed, but this is not the case.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Also, should this be used in web? Are there any consequences?

Comment: You write: "when clicking on link that is in this format, network tab reports status code 200 for that website". Are you sure that this is going to behave like that? Basically, the the SSL handling is configured via web server settings. This means that different sites can react differently to each scheme format. If your goal is to configure specific behavior, then please precise your question.

Comment: I am just curious about how does ```//mywebsite.com``` link works, and why is there so little documentation about it

Comment: I don't know what website it is, but definitely such behavior is not reproducible on mu side. Maybe that's a browser setting? Which browser are you using? Are you clicking on a link on a web page, or just typing this by hand?

Comment: Browser is Chrome and I am clicking on a link located on a webpage.

Comment: So it is not the request handling which translates //mywebsite.com to https://mywebsite.com but browser's HTML presentation. Please, observe that if you hover on `a` tag with such `href` attribute, you will see that the target address is already modified by Chrome (you can check it by right-clicking and copying the target address). On the other hand, if you paste //mywebsite.com directly into browser, the request won't be handled correctly.